# Gentoo and Systemd: Can openrc be uninstalled without breaking other packages?

Tags: gentoo, systemd

I switched my Gentoo system from openrc to systemd, and everything seems to run fine as long as both are installed.

Nevertheless, after `emerge --depclean`, which removes openrc, the gentoolkit program revdep-rebuild does not work any more (it misses /etc/init.d/functions.sh and the einfo command). Now the question is, can I get rid of openrc (and sysvinit) without breaking packages, and if yes, how?

Should I wait with further steps until [bug 373219](https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=373219) is fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should wait until that bug is fixed :)